# Platform Specific Natives in Python

Tags: python, c, native

[This page](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) goes over the specifics of how to extend Python with C. However, I didn't see anything about using different C code depending on the OS.

I'm fairly sure this can be done, because the python library [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) has cross platform terminal color support, which as far as I know needs different code for Windows and Unix. However, I looked through the [source code](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) and couldn't find anything. It should be noted that I may have missed it because neither python nor C is my area of expertise.

**TL;DR:** How does one extend python using OS-specific C code?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KSFT I added a TL;DR, "How does one extend python using OS-specific C code?"

Comment: I don't think the process for writing a Python library in C changes depending on whether the code is OS-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in C this is done using conditional compilation.  Most compilers will have a pre-processor macro indicating the OS.  For example:

```
#ifdef WIN32
     // do Windows stuff
#else
     // do something else
#endif
```

The names of these macros are compiler specific.

Alternatively my preferred option is to place OS specific code in its own DLL or shared object and link the code into your platform-independent python interface.

For example, you write the Python interface as being portable, when you get to something which is OS specific you make a call to a generic function of your own invention.  There is a copy of this generic function in each shared library for Linux, Windows, OS X, etc which is resolved at linker time.

Whether to go for conditional compilation or OS specific libraries depends on how much code is different.